# wmuslider only loads sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently making a website for a dance studio and am using the wmuslider to create a slider in the middle of the homepage. Only problem is that the slider sometimes loads and sometimes doesn't. I found that this is a problem in all the browsers I use: Chrome, Firefox and Explorer. I'm guessing this is a problem with the jquery script. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Aleks

The website is: http://www.aleksdesign.ca/dance/

Answer (score 0):

Browsers might be trying to initialise the slider before the DOM is ready. Wait till its ready:

```
<script>  
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var options = {touch: true, animation: "slide"};
    $(".wmuSlider").wmuSlider(options);
});
</script>
```

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Tried adding a $(document).ready but unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes in demo.css

```
.wmuSlider {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
set some height ->  height: 100px;
}
.wmuSlider .wmuSliderWrapper {
remove -> display:none
}
```